# Is there a way to sync in-memory data between two concurrent invocations of the same serverless function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, serverless, aws-serverless

Is there a way to sync data between two concurrent invocations of the same lambda/cloud function?

Can a proxy be used for this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample scenario for your requirement?

Comment: Not using Google Cloud Functions features. Edit your question to clearly describe what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Functions v1 uses a single concurrency model. Concurrent invocations on Google Cloud Functions v1 will never run on the same instance, so there's no way to share data in memory between them.

Outside of that, you can store the data on any [storage service](https://cloud.google.com/storage) to share it between the invocations. For example, [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore) or my personal favorite: the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/)